# How to (within code) Disconnect from SQL Connection on Incorrect Table Name?

Tags: oracle, batch-file, sqlplus

**Scenario**:

I have a batch script that calls a .sql file via sqlplus. The .sql file is as follows:

```
set serveroutput on
variable out_val varchar2;
exec &1;
print out_val
exit
```

**Issue**:

The batch script passes a string on which the .sql executes. I expect that this string be correct 99% of the time, but I need to plan for that last 1% because the batch will be called once every 5 minutes. When the .sql is passed the correct login information and schema but the incorrect table name, my batch hangs and does not automatically close itself. Instead, it stays logged in to the sql connection until I hit Ctrl+C and manually close it. I tried the following TRY/CATCH block but it didn't change the issue:

```
set serveroutput on
variable out_val varchar2;
begin try
exec &1;
end try
begin catch
exit
end catch
print out_val
exit
```

**Question**:

How do I code either a batch script or a sql code block to automatically disconnect from a sql connection if the inputted table name is incorrect? (Note that I can't use IF statements to test every possible table name, there are too many and they may change often. It needs to be able to disconnect if the table name cannot be found.)

Comment: Perhaps put `kill connection_id();` in place of `exit` in your catch block?

Comment: Please tag carefully. MySQL != SQLServer != Oracle.

Comment: John, adding that in place of the exit did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT FAILURE ROLLBACK    
set serveroutput on
variable out_val varchar2;
exec &1;
print out_val
exit
```

Comment: This worked like a charm. I know I didn't explain what the executable function was, but I removed "FAILURE ROLLBACK" (because I didn't need it) and the code works perfectly. Thanks Ten!

Comment: Ok, weird. I just removed that line you added and ran my batch, and it works properly. Not sure what's going on.

Comment: The WHENEVER SQLERROR remains effective for the duration of the session (exit, or until you issue WHENEVER SQLERROR CONTINUE), i.e. if you run it once then remain connected, and you editted the script to remove the line whilst in the session you will see that it still works. If you exit sqlplus and try the script without the WHENEVER you might fid it reverts back. Read up on sqlplus WHENEVER to understand this fully.

Comment: Ahh, alright. That makes sense. I've added it back in. Thanks again for your help!